# Distinguish "available & busy" from Google Calendar "Private adress" iCal link

Tags: php, json, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am retrieving a iCal from a Google Calendar `"Private adress"` link in JSON format.

[image]

I can see both events that are `available` and `busy` but can not see any difference between them. I imported them to PHP, also tried the `?alt=json` option to get a JSON object but no where saw a distinction between both.

But if I look at the same calendar shared with me with the `free/busy information (Hide details)` option checked, then I only see the busy events.

Is there a way to distinguish them in the iCal so I can import them into my PHP functions and not mix events that exist but are marked as available with events marked as busy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a difference in the value for `TRANSP`.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.2.7

Comment: Bingo! There was the difference. Thank you!